# How is OpenCL floatn different from a custom struct

Tags: struct, opencl

I'm having problems passing a structure of vectors to an OpenCL kernel.

Long story short, I have found that I CAN pass a C structure:

```
typedef struct {
    cl_float4 vec;
} my_type;
```

. . . to a kernel, if I declare it like:

```
typedef struct { float s[4]; } my_float4;
typedef struct { my_float4 vec; } my_type; //use custom float4
__kernel void function(const my_type test) {}
```

. . . but NOT, if I declare it like:

```
typedef struct { float4 vec; } my_type; //use built-in float4
__kernel void function(const my_type test) {}
```

So my question is, what makes a float4 different and special?  In the second example, I get CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE on clSetKernelArg.  In the host code, I'm using cl_float4--isn't that *supposed* to be paired with float4 in the kernel?

EDIT: by request, the clSetKernelArg code (error handling cropped):

```
template <typename type_data> void set_argument(int arg_index, const type_data* data) {
    cl_int err = clSetKernelArg(kernel,arg_index,sizeof(type_data),data);
    if (err!=CL_SUCCESS) throw "ERROR"; /*simplified*/
}
```

I call the function with a struct declared exactly as above:

```
my_type test;
my_kernel->set_argument(0,&test);
```

Comment: Can you show the exact clSetKernelArg call and associated code? It is likely to be a structure alignment issue, but hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: Added the function.  The structure is already the exact code.

Comment: Still missing the template instantiation.....

Comment: There isn't an explicit one.  It's declared that way in the header file.  From the called code, you can infer that the compiler will instantiate .set_argument<my_type>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug with your implementation - you should be able to pass that user-defined type to a kernel without issue.  What platform / SDK are you using?  I was able to successfully declare this type in host code:

```
typedef struct _mytype {
    cl_float4 val;
} mytype;
```

... and then later use it:

```
mytype t;
status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, argc++, sizeof(mytype), &t);
check_status("clSetKernelArg:mytype t", status);
```

Where check_status does what you'd expect: checks for a non-`CL_SUCCESS` return value.

The kernel looks like this:

```
typedef struct _mytype {
  float4 value;
} mytype;

kernel void do_it(/* ... */, const mytype test) { /* ... */ }
```

This compiles and executes, giving correct results on the CPU device.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried this exact example and it worked.  I then failed to reproduce my problem with the same code I used before.  However, I did run into another snag--you can't mix cl_float3 and cl_float.  I figured out that you need four floats (alignment), which fixed it.  So . . . not sure what the original problem was :S  Thanks for helping me though!